# RapidClipse multiplies code, how to fix it?

Tags: error-handling, rapidclipse

I am new to RapidClipse and Java development.

I played around a little bit with RapidClipse 4.0 functions (Win 10 pro) and for this purpose, I generated a page to modify a MySql database table. This page includes a table and a FieldGroup like in a RapidClipse example video.

After working and playing with the functions and Vaadin styles, I got around 20 errors.

A little bit later: 40 errors
once again a little bit later: 60 errors and so on.

"duplicate field...."

I assume the reason for the errors is a bug in the code generator, because in the Java classes of the page are still regions with generated code.

It is not possible to modify these areas.

Just a little bit of the code:

```
// <generated-code name="variables">
private XdevLabel lblDmvId, lblDmvCol00, lblDmvCol01;
private XdevButton cmdReset, cmdNew, cmdSave, cmdSaveAndNew;
private XdevFieldGroup<OkmDbMetadataValue> fieldGroupManContacts;
private XdevHorizontalLayout horizontalLayout;
private XdevGridLayout formManContact;
private XdevTextField txtDmvId, txtDmvCol00, txtDmvCol01;
private XdevVerticalLayout verticalLayout;
private XdevContainerFilterComponent containerFilterComponent;
private XdevTable<OkmDbMetadataValue> tblOkmContacts;
// </generated-code>
// <generated-code name="variables">
private XdevLabel lblDmvId, lblDmvCol00, lblDmvCol01;
private XdevButton cmdReset, cmdNew, cmdSave, cmdSaveAndNew;
private XdevFieldGroup<OkmDbMetadataValue> fieldGroupManContacts;
private XdevHorizontalLayout horizontalLayout;
```

It seems, that the generated code is still multiplied.

Once again, I am not able to modify anything there. I tried to modify the code on the operating system level, by editing it by a plain text editor - without success.

Is there any idea how to fix this problem?

I tried to place it in RapidClipse forum. But this is also not possible, because the forum has still a bug too. The captcha did not work - it is still outdated.

I tried to write a mail to XDEV-germany. Since two days without any feedback/ success :-((

Answer (score 0):

After I got no support and after I found no solution
I decided to throw the page into the wastebasket.
I rebuild the page from scratch and everything worked fine.
Out of this, the question can be closed without solution.